# Parse: findInBackground only returns results for currentUser

Tags: parse-platform

I've searched and searched with no luck.

FYI: I'm a newbie...I'm trying to query a class for non-current user data. I've verified that user_objectID and userID are correct and that Parse has these files, but the list shows up as 0. When I switch userID to my ID then it works.

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Workouts");
query.whereEqualTo("user_objectID", userID);
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
    @Override
    public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            Log.v(TAG, userID + ": " + list.size());
            for (ParseObject each : list) {
                Log.v(TAG, each.getDouble("distance") + "");
            }
        } else {
            Log.v(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    }
});
```

What am I doing wrong? Is it a setting? Am I not using the right query paramters?

Thanks so much for any insight.
Tyler

Comment: Do you have any ACL applied to the objects stored in your Workouts collection? If yes, check what the read/write permissions are.

Comment: @BjörnKaiser - the ACL pertains to the user making the query, and it appears that the app's user is permitted to read the "Workouts" table (because sometimes the query returns results).  My guess is that the `userID` being passed doesn't match anything in the user_objectID column of that table.

Comment: @danh I've played around with the ACL settings with no luck either. I've set read/write to public for the user I'm trying to query and still no results. I've verified that the user_objectID matches as well. My previous query to my "_User" class is pulling the userID from an email address query.

Comment: The next most likely issue is the confusion between objects, pointers and object ids.  What is the column type on Workouts of the user_objectID column?  "ID" makes it sound like a string, but it could be a pointer or a relation.  What is the type and value of userID in the code snippet?  It's name sort of implies string also.

Comment: @danh thank you so much for the help! user_objectID column is type String. userID is also a String. When I go to parse.com and filter user_objectID by the string from the log, I get the results as expected.

Comment: Did you hardcode that id into the query, instead of the userId variable in the code?

Comment: it's the variable, but I've tried hardcoding it and the result is the same.